# Error en método asíncrono estático

Tags: android, android-fragment, android-asynctask

Me encuentro realizando correcciones en un método asíncrono el problema es que necesito que sea estático a lo cual me lleva a unos cuantos errores al momento de llenar el método asíncrono pero me ocurren los siguientes errores:

[image: Error al utilizar un getAtivity y un getReources]

Y el otro error es este:

[image: Error al utilizar getAtivity]

¿Alguna idea del porque sea ese error?

```
 for(Fragment f: getActivity.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()){
                if(f!= null) {
                    if (f.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MesFragment")) {
                        ((MesFragment) f).refreshCalendar();
                    }
                    if (f.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("SemanaFragment")) {
                        ((SemanaFragment) f).calendar = (Calendar) globalVariable.calendar.clone();
                        ((SemanaFragment) f).refreshWeek();
                    }
                    if (f.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("DiaFragment")) {
                        ((DiaFragment) f).calendar = (Calendar)globalVariable.calendar.clone();
                        ((DiaFragment) f).refreshDay();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: es preferible que escribas el código, en vez de poner imágenes de tu código.

Comment: Lo se y gracias por la recomendación es que ya tenia preparadas las imágenes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El metodo [`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) pertenece a la clase `Fragment` no a la clase `AsyncTask<T,T,T>`.

Pasale como parametro al constructor la referencia del clase `Activity` a tu clase `getEventsAsyncTask`:

```
static class getEventsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>
{

  private Activity _activity;
  public getEventsAsyncTask(Activity activity)
  {
    this._activity= activity;
  }
  @Override
  public void onPreExecute()
  { 
    progressBar = new ProgressDialog(this._activity);
    //...
  }
}
```

Actualizacion:

He estado investado acerca del segundo error que tienes y lo que quieres no es posible con el codigo actual.  `FragmentManager#getFragments()` no es una API publica y solo es permitida utilizarla internamente por el sistema.

Te recomiendo guardar la referencia de los fragmentos en algun lugar y pasarlo como parametros tambien al `AsyncTask` para hacer lo que necesites.

Comment: Muchas gracias si me funcionó, pero alguna idea para el cazo de la segunda imagen? se podría hacer lo mismo que se hizo para la primera?

Comment: Si. Puedes hacer lo mismo

Comment: Es que lo probé pero al parecer me marco error lo que hice fue `Fragment f: this.activity1.getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments())` 
Pero para la propiedad getSupportFragmentManager marca error

Comment: `getSupportFragmentManager()` pertenece a `FragmentActivity` como support library. Para obtener el `FragmentManager` utiliza `_activity.getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Ese lo puedo usar directo en esa linea es decir de tal manera que quede así `Fragment f: activity1.getFragmentManager().getFragment()`?

Comment: Cual es tu intencion con el fragmentMananger? Para que lo necesitas

Comment: Necesito interacción entre los fragmentos, puse el código para que sea mas claro lo que quiero hacer

Comment: Actualize mi respuesta. Dale una miradita

Comment: de verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Siempre hermano.